# Blocking connections at SVRCONN channels

Tags: ibm-mq

Is there a way to block connections on an MQ SVRCONN channel based on the client version?

I am running MQ v9.3 and in some of my SVRCONN channels, I don't wanna allow MQ v8 Clients to connect to it.

Do anyway see a way to achieve that?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in the MQ product itself. You'd have to use a channel security exit to do it. The MQCXP structure passed to the exit contains `RemoteVersion` that tells you the version of the connecting client.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct solution to your problem but there is a product called [MQ Channel Connection Inspector](https://www.capitalware.com/mqcci_overview.html) that is a Channel Security Exit which will output information related to the incoming connection request. It logs information like RemoteProduct, RemoteVersion, hostname/IP, channel name, UserId, etc..

Hence, you could use the file as an audit trail and chase down the offending client application.